# Stored Procedure COMPILE Error

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can Someone help me on this , this is the error message I am getting when I run this script

> ```
>     ERROR at line 1:
>     ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
>     ORA-06321: at "s3398293.P2", line 7
>     ORA-06321: at "s3398293.P2", line 18
>     ORA-06321: at line 1
> ```

The code:

```
    create or replace 
    PROCEDURE p2(x NUMBER ) 
    as
        staff_info  staff.bno%TYPE;
        address_info varchar2(20);

            CURSOR c1 IS
                SELECT staff.bno ,
                branch.street || ' ' || branch.suburb || ' ' || branch.postcode 
                FROM deal , staff, contact , property , branch
                where staff.peid = contact.peid
                and contact.pno = property.pno
                and property.pno = deal.pno 
                and staff.peid = branch.peid
                group by staff.bno
                HAVING x > sum(deal.price);

   BEGIN
         OPEN c1;
         LOOP
            FETCH c1 INTO staff_info,address_info ;
            EXIT WHEN c1%notfound;
            dbms_output.put_line('BRANCH# '||' '||'ADDRESS');
            dbms_output.put_line(staff_info ||' '|| address_info);  
         END LOOP;
         close c1;
   END;
   /
```

Can Someone tell me more about GROUP BY EXPRESSION! ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the cursor statement as follows (**EDIT 2!**):

```
            SELECT staff.bno staff_info,
            branch.street || ' ' || branch.suburb || ' ' || branch.postcode address_info
            FROM deal , staff, contact , property , branch
            where staff.peid = contact.peid
            and contact.pno = property.pno
            and property.pno = deal.pno 
            and staff.peid = branch.peid
            group by staff.bno ,
            branch.street || ' ' || branch.suburb || ' ' || branch.postcode 
            HAVING sum(deal.price) < x;
```

**EDIT - as per comments:**

Your `LOOP` should look as follows:

```
     FOR R IN C1
     LOOP
        staff_info := R.staff_info;
        address_info := R.address_info;
        dbms_output.put_line('BRANCH# '||' '||'ADDRESS');
        dbms_output.put_line(staff_info ||' '|| address_info);  
     END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks. But Is there anything wrong with my LOOP because it is fetching only one row....

Comment: please see my EDIT above... and don't forget to upvote/mark as accepted any answer that was of help...

Comment: I got errors asking me that Staff_info and address_info need to be declared. but I have already declared them in the declaration block.

Comment: please see my EDIT 2... you need to alias the columns from the SELECT used in the CURSOR...

Comment: Thanks. could you please explain your First EDIT. I did not understand alias stuff ?

Comment: for example in `staff.bno staff_info` the `staff_info` is called an alias, it is a new name for the column in the resultset (CURSOR)